# Is there such a thing as "exception exit"?

Tags: python, exception, exit

So I know that there are a whole lot of Exception variations like `except KeyboardInterrupt` that runs when you `Ctrl + c` etc. But is there an exception where a block of code runs when the user tries to manually close the program (X button)?

(I couldn't find this answer online so if you could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated)

Comment: @Ahmadhassan: That's not going to help - atexit handlers don't run when the program is terminated abruptly.

Comment: You are right @user2357112 supports Monica

Comment: @Ahmadhassan I am not using any kind of GUI. I was wondering if it's still possible with a standard terminal? Or like the python exe and VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

On POSIX-compliant systems you can capture this event by setting a handler for the [SIGHUP](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGHUP) signal.  Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP)

> On POSIX-compliant platforms, SIGHUP ("signal hang up") is a signal sent to a process when its controlling terminal is closed

Here's an example based on the code in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#example):

```py
import os
import signal


def handler(signum, frame):
    with open('parent-process-ended.txt', 'w') as f:
        msg = f'Parent process {os.getppid()} of process {os.getpid()} has ended\n'
        f.write(msg)


signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, handler)

while True:
    pass
```